# Using AudioKit with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, audiokit

I would like to add waveform plot features to my sound recorder/player, using Objective-C. I discovered the AudioKit 4 which seems a great framework, and I imported the AudioKit & AudioKitUI frameworks from audiokit.io website. I am using Xcode 9 with iOS10.0 target. Unfortunately I cannot initialize some classes from the AudioKit in my objective-C code... For example, to create an AKAudioPlayer instance, I use:

```
AKAudioFile *audioFile = [[AKAudioFile alloc] initForReading: myURL error:&error];  
AKAudioPlayer* playerAK = [[AKAudioPlayer alloc] initWithFile:audioFile looping:NO deferBuffering:false completionHandler:nil];
```

From what I understand from Apple documentation on using swift framework in Objective-C, I thought that the  `initWithFile: looping: deferBuffering: completionHandler:` was the good translation in objective-C from the swift init call defined in AKAudioPlayer.swift in AudioKit framework:

```
public init(file: AKAudioFile,
                looping: Bool = false,
                deferBuffering: Bool = false,
                completionHandler: AKCallback? = nil) throws...
```

The AKAudioFile object instantiation causes neither warning nor error. But on instantiation of AKAudioPlayer, the compiler returns an error, saying no interface declares the selector `initWithFile: looping: deferBuffering: completionHandler:`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

AudioKit was just released as 4.0.1 to correct some bugs. So my question is now obsolete!

Answer (score 0):

By cmd-clicking the `AKAudioPlayer` you can see the interface exposed to objective-c, the only available `init` is:

```
- (nonnull instancetype)init SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Properties relevant to loading a file would be:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) AKAudioFile * _Nonnull audioFile;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString * _Nonnull path;
```

Since the 1st is read only I'd give a shot with the latter one. So you'd end up with:

```
@import AudioKit;

- (void)inSomeMethod {
    AKAudioPlayer *player = [[AKAudioplayer alloc] init];
    player.path = @"/myPath/To/audioFile";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But AKAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioplayer alloc] init]; create the same compiler error... (by the way it is AKAudioPlayer not AVAudioPlayer)

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, I've been working with `AVAudioPlayer` on daily basis recently and it sticks to my head. Anyway can you instantiate `[[AKAudioPlayer alloc] init]` aka `[AKAudioPlayer new]`? Btw there's an example on the repo https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Examples/iOS/HelloObjectiveC , perhaps it'll get you started.